# Removing and then installing webtatic repository on centos 5.8

Tags: linux, installation, centos, repository

steps for Removing and then installing webtatic repository on centos 5.8 installed on linux server.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do visit: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask a good question and have, if possible, some answers to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

---

Removing a package, ( webtatic.repo ) : `# yum remove latest.rpm`

Adding the webtatic.repo : Download 'latest.rpm' http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el5/latest.rpm , and do `# cd Downloads/ && yum install latest.rpm`

Or do this : `# rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el5/latest.rpm`

Ref. https://webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/

---

Comment: Thanks...your solution worked on that very day....but thanking today...better late than never